# Get and remove all currently displayed notifications from SP.UI.Notify

Tags: web-part, javascript

I am sending a variety of notifications via

```
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("blah", true);
```

setting the "sticky bit" to true so that the notification stays visible.  When I display a second notification, I want to remove the current notification, but I need the id of the notification to remove it with

```
SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(id)
```

Is there any way to remove all of the current notifications or to get the ids of the the current notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same requirement as you on my last project and used the same approach that you did:

[Edit- moved from within question]

```
var currentNotificationID = "";

function replaceNotification(message) {

    if(currentNotificationID != "") {
        SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(currentNotificationID);
    }

    currentNotificationID = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(message, true);

    return;
}

function showError() {

    replaceNotification('Error message...');

    return;
}
```

[End Edit]

The API doesn't offer the method you're looking for on the [SP.UI.Notify class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550701.aspx).

It does however offer this method on the SP.UI.Status class:

```
SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
```

Would this be an acceptable alternative?  [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408763.aspx) for more MSDN documentation on the SP.UI.Status class.

Comment: I was asked to use Notify over Status, but the above worked well enough for what I needed. I added this solution to your answer and will mark accepted once my edit gets peer reviewed. Feel free to change it.